# SoundTouch and QuickSeek setting

Tags: c#, soundtouch

When I change tempo in Audacity (sound application) - it modifies test.wav very fast (1 sec). Now when I process same file in my application, it takes 27 seconds. I call soundtouch.dll functions via interop. When I apply QuickSeek, it take same amount of time to process smaple file. No difference. Anyone had same problems? I use soundtouch.dll downloaded from orginal website and with float sample type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Had to send small blocks (max 100kB) in loop instead of one big block (like in example at soundtouch homepage). All was in loop, after each block I sent, I tried to receive new processed data. And it took now 200x time less than before. Now using QuickSeek gives noticeable processing time boost.